# To find the $n$-th power of a Jordan block such that there is no complex entries.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}7&3\\ \:-3&7\end{pmatrix}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. We need to find the $n$-th power of $A$ such that there is no complex entries.

Note that $A$ is a Jordan block. I tried with the eigenvector method but it gives complex entries.

Comment: What is your definition of Jordan block?  I think of a Jordan block as having $\lambda$ on the diagonal, $1$ on the super-diagonal, and $0$ elsewhere?  Also, $A$ is a real matrix.  No power of it will have complex entries.

Comment: I guess that the refence to "complex entries" is to exclude the method of diagonalizing $A$ and using that. Of course, the end result will have integer entries, but the formula for them involves complex numbers.

Comment: As a way for you to show some effort here's a hint: Can you write $A$ as $\sqrt{58}$ times the matrix representing rotation by the angle $\arcsin(3/\sqrt{58})$? That won't produce "obvious integers" either, but there won't be any complex numbers!

Comment: Ok, the previous comment was a bad joke. I would use the eigenvectors $(1,\pm i)^T$ and simplify the end result. I would think you end with sum formulas from using the binomial formula at some point.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}7&3\\ \:-3&7\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A = 7\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:0&1\end{pmatrix}+3 \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ \:-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A=7I+3N$$
With $N^{2n}=(-1)^nI$ and $N^{2n+1}=(-1)^nN$. And $N$ and $I$ commute. Then use binomial theorem to find $A^n$